# Android studio showing file not present, even when it is present

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried cleaning the project and even then it says that file not present when i try to build but it shows the same error.
I did however restored an earlier version of the file after which this error has appeared. I made sure that the file is present in the hard disk
Here is the logcat

```
Warning:string 'setting_legal' has no default translation.
D:\Android\26 aug 17\12novplayerafterad\laMusique2May2016\src\main\java\bitsie\playmee\musicplayer\free\fragments\BaseSongFragment.java
Error:(61, 26) error: package MetaTagEditDialog does not exist
D:\Android\26 aug 17\12novplayerafterad\laMusique2May2016\src\main\java\bitsie\playmee\musicplayer\free\fragments\FragmentFolder.java
Error:(70, 26) error: package MetaTagEditDialog does not exist
D:\Android\26 aug 17\12novplayerafterad\laMusique2May2016\src\main\java\bitsie\playmee\musicplayer\free\playback\MediaPlayerFragment.java
Error:(97, 26) error: package MetaTagEditDialog does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':laMusique2May2016:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 9.203 secs
Information:4 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..
```